# Extract the latest date time from a string

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I have the following value of column in string format like:

row 1

```
PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B) FCX[36]@03/22 17:03 (272497-B)LDX[44]@03/22 17:01 (272497-N)
```

row 2

```
PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B)LDX[44]@03/22 17:01 (272497-N)
```

row 3

```
PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B)
```

Need to get the latest date for each row (`03/22 17:03` for row1) and convert it to `DateTime`

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/21 14:34", "MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Need your help with extracting the latest date from the string. I don't understand how to use `Regex` to get this to work. Please suggest

Comment: @JeremyThompson this is not a duplicate!! I don't have a list of dates! I have a string with many dates

Comment: why do you want to use Regex? Seems that it is the fixed value string so `string.Substring` will extract the string date representation from the line. Then you can convert extracted string values to date list and find the latest

Comment: @oleksa sometime in that string can be 1 row, sometimes 2 or 3 as in the question. How can I use substring for it?

Comment: What you need to do is, for each string, use string.Substring to extract the date time portion.  Then use ParseExact to convert each substring to a DateTime.  This results in a list of DateTimes.  Then use the standard ways to find the latest DateTime from the collection.  If all of your data is in a single string, split it into an array of strings using String.Split

Comment: 1 string contains `PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B)
FCX[36]@03/22 17:03 (272497-B)
LDX[44]@03/22 17:01 (272497-N)` how to get the lasts one?

Comment: @oleksa Thanks for the idea, I will try

Comment: well, is it fixed length strings ? I mean is the `PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B)` has the same length ? You can split long strings (like row1) for small parts and then substring the date representation from the each part

Comment: @JeremyThompson explain please why is it a duplicate?

Comment: you can try to use regex like `@(\d\d/\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d)`. It will find all date-like groups from the string. Run the `Regex.Matches` for all string rows and collect date string representation to the one list. Then convert to date time and scan for the latest date

Comment: @Chebur I suspect that it needs the year to do the DateTime parsing because of leap years. Otherwise it might assume the current year at run-time and fail for 02/29 when the current year is not a leap year. **What year should be used?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way

```
private static DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateTimeStr)
{
      var records = dateTimeStr.Split("\r\n");

      // example PLX[12]@03/21 14:34 (475573-B)            
       return records
          .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Substring(8, 11), "MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
          .Max();
 }
```

Thanks to @oleksa for suggestions